# Turn off USB power when system not in use on motherboard

Tags: usb, audio, motherboard

I have an Asus Z77 sabertooth motherboard.  I also just got a USB powered audio DAC for my desk.  It has a very bright white light on the front of it and it only turns off when there's no power going to the device.  Unfortunately even when my system is powered off the light stays on which makes it hard for me to sleep.

I have tried putting lightdims over the light but since it protrudes a bit it doesn't stay on very well and it's so bright that the light sneaks out of the cracks of the device.

I'd really just love for the power on my usb ports to turn off when my system is off.  Right now I have needed to unplug it every night which is a real pain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if there is an option in the BIOS?  Also, have you tried the other USB ports?

If neither of those works, what you need is something like the **Sabrent 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub with Individual Power Switches and LEDs (HB-UMLS)** available at the most popular online retailers.

I would provide a direct link, but I don't know if that is permitted.  A simple search on Amazon will find it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was a hidden option in the Bios called ErP Ready.  When the system is shutdown it allows the system to go into the S5 state.  So if you enable ErP Ready you will have a lot of power saved but the power button will still work.

EUP settings has no effect.